# Highlight Select tag option from keyboard inout

Tags: javascript, html

Well, Its one of those common feature you have in all website with Select tags. I have a list of countries in a select tag. Now, I want that, if I press 'I' from keyboard, the first Country names that start with 'I' will get selected.. 
I tried some java script fount in internet. but they didn't work..

A snippet will be of immense help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any browser in common use that doesn't support that as a standard feature of its implementation of a select element.

You don't need JavaScript, they just work that way.

Comment: +1, *they just work that way...* unless you're stupid enough to prepend spaces to each option text like I've seen on some websites.  I hate that!

Comment: Ohkay. But you see, My list consists of a hell lot of options. So instead of keeping them in source page, I'm keeping them in a php page(I'm working on php), and just echoing them in the main page as html code.

And its not working out that way.

Comment: The client (i.e. the browser) cannot know and does not care if the HTML was provided by a static file or a server side program. It requests a URI and gets an HTML document, that is all.